# Anonymous user not redirected to log in page which was previously working

Tags: commerce, users, redirection

When any anonymous user clicks on Checkout button then he/she will be　redirected to log in page. Previously this functionality was working very fine. But then I was researching on it, I unchecked the permission of "Access checkout" for anonymous user. I checked what happens doing that. Afterwards I reverted the change.

But from that time I'm not able to redirect anonymous user to log in page. Also site does not show the Checkout button without logging in.

I will try by adding rules. But how come this functionality broke down?

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Have you cleared caches? Re-check permissions page, clear cache, check dblog errors (Recent log messages, provided by dblog module)

Comment: Yes, I cleared the site cache from admin side as well as browser cache. Will check with the error logs.

Comment: @tunic I couldn't found anything in dblog reports. Also I rechecked the permissions. But it's not helping me. What should I do?